Panel icon in KDE not displaying correctly
I am asking this question again because the issue has still not been resolved. I installed an application from a .deb file using 'sudo dpkg -i...' and pinned it to the panel. I am running Kubuntu 24.04 LTS
The app works fine and the icon does momentarily show when I click on the icon pinned to the panel but then gives way to a grey box with an 'X' in it (see screenshot).
The .desktop file looks ok. Any advice appreciated.

The icon appears correctly in the start up menu

it was a typo. I meant 24.04

Can you copy paste the contents of the desktop file in your question. The screenshot is not readable

This question is similar to: Icon not displaying correctly on KDE Plasma panel. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here is the content of the desktop file                                                                     :[Desktop Entry]
Name=Waveform13
GenericName=Waveform
Comment=Audio and MIDI workstation
Exec=/usr/bin/Waveform13 %u
Icon=waveform13
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;AudioEditing;
MimeType=application/x-waveform13-project;
Version=1.0
